# SQL query improvement/suggestions required

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to solve this question:

#### Write a query to return the number of rentals per movie, and the average number of rentals in its same category.

- You only need to return results for film_id <= 10.
  Return 4 columns: film_id, category name, number of rentals, and the average number of rentals from its category.

```sql
Table 1: inventory
Each row is unique; Inventoy_id is the primary key of the table

   col_name   | col_type
--------------+--------------------------
 inventory_id | integer
 film_id      | smallint
 store_id     | smallint
Table 2: film_category
A film can only belong to one category

  col_name   | col_type
-------------+--------------------------
 film_id     | smallint
 category_id | smallint
Table 3: rental
   col_name   | col_type
--------------+--------------------------
 rental_id    | integer
 rental_ts    | timestamp with time zone
 inventory_id | integer
 customer_id  | smallint
 return_ts    | timestamp with time zone
 staff_id     | smallint
Table 4: category
Movie categories.

  col_name   | col_type
-------------+--------------------------
 category_id | integer
 name        | text
Sample results

 film_id | category_name | rentals | avg_rentals_category
---------+---------------+---------+----------------------
       1 | Documentary   |      23 |  16.6666666666666667
       2 | Horror        |       7 |  15.9622641509433962
       3 | Documentary   |      12 |  16.6666666666666667
       4 | Horror        |      23 |  15.9622641509433962
```

My Query:

```sql
select film_id, category_name, rentals,
       avg(rentals) over(partition by category_name)
from
(
  select fc.film_id, 
       c.name as category_name , 
       count(distinct rental_id) as rentals
from category c 
join film_category fc on fc.category_id = c.category_id
join inventory i on i.film_id = fc.film_id
join rental r on i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
group by fc.film_id, category_name
) temp
where film_id <=10;
```

I am just getting different values for last column. I am wondering what am I doing wrong? Please try to help me with suggestions on my written query so that I can continue improving my window function skills.
Thanks!

Comment: Please replace your unclear scheme with complete CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO with sample data. Show desired output for this data. And add detailed explanations which refers to definite rows and values. Also provide **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: please provide db scripts

Comment: unfortunately, i am practicing online so i might not have access to create scripts